# Can I connect a button to a struct within a new swift file in xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to add a UIButton function to a struct within a supplementary swift file in xcode, but whenever I hold the command button and drag the button to the swift code, nothing appears. I'm very new to xcode so any help explaining how I may deal with this would be greatly appreciated.

Do i have to declare a class first or something?

Thank you

Comment: no, structs are value types whereas classes are reference types.

Comment: @jbiser I currently have a struct with 4 arrays and I wanted to pull a combination of arrays based on what my UI objects state are enabled/disabled arrays. Would I be unable to do this with a struct then?

Comment: Theoretically yes

Answer (score 1):

You need to start with a class that inherits from UIViewController.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html